# Using pandas from the source directory

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to import and use pandas module in my script, **but** without having to install it on my machine, rather using it from the source directory. What is the best way to achieve this?

**I have tried:** adding pandas egg file to my source directory, but when I try to import the module, I get the following error

```
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I've also tried to add numpy's egg file to the source directory, but it didn't work out

Comment: Did you follow all their instructions from their `contributing.md` file?

Comment: have you tried virtualenv?

Comment: @EuRBamarth no, I did not. Where can I find this file?

Comment: Here - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/contributing.html

Comment: Just out of interest - why don't you want to install it on your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating an [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) and making it [relocatable](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#making-environments-relocatable) should solve your problem.

```
pip install virtualenv        # install virtualenv
virtualenv env                # create env
pip install pandas            # install pandas
virtualenv --relocatable env  # make env relocatable
```